# Substrate build failure with `--runtime-benchmarks` flag

Tags: build

```
git checkout 91b97b016618fcc515f55a15b1f008b68e13f5a2
cargo check --features runtime-benchmarks
```

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (/root/code/self/substrate/client/network/bitswap)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/root/code/self/substrate/target/debug/build/sc-network-bitswap-23c560e6e0d6a1a2/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
  this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
  it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
  installed `protoc` binary.

  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc
  ', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.11.1/src/lib.rs:1227:10
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: `apt install protobuf-compiler` on Debian.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Arch `pacman -S protobuf` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted the solution to your own question:

```
Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your 
installed `protoc` binary.
```

As this is saying. Please install `protoc` and make sure that the binary is available in the global `PATH` or set the `PROTOC` environment variable pointing to the binary.

Comment: Is there a new update? I don't need this before. We should put this on Substrate doc (maybe there is one but I didn't find it).

Comment: Yeah, `prost-build` was updated: https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/pull/657

Comment: https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/ it is also already mentioned here as required package.

Comment: `brew install protobuf` on macos.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a crate dependency....

Try installing this: *sudo apt install --assume-yes git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev make protobuf-compiler*