# Error while Compile the subkey program using the nightly toolchain

Tags: subkey

I [follow this reference tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/#subkey-generate) to subkey-generate. While compiling subkey program using `cargo +nightly build --package subkey --release`, I faced this issue.

[image]

Someone explain what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same as [Substrate build failure with `--runtime-benchmarks` flag](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/substrate-build-failure-with-runtime-benchmarks-flag).

Try install `protobuf` with your system package manager.

Comment: Thanks it success after `protobuf installation`.