# Could not find `protoc` installation when compiling substrate-node-template v0.9.30

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am compiling the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) tag version [v0.9.30](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/polkadot-v0.9.30) on my Apple M1 and I get the following error:

```sh
   Compiling multiaddr v0.14.0
   Compiling cid v0.8.6
   Compiling scale-info v2.2.0
   Compiling impl-codec v0.6.0
   Compiling sp-storage v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
   Compiling sp-tracing v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
   Compiling fork-tree v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
   Compiling sp-version-proc-macro v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
   Compiling k256 v0.10.4
   Compiling sp-panic-handler v4.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
error: failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-bitswap v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/bruno/src/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/sc-network-bitswap-b81f77b4f38731d7/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
  this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
  it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
  installed `protoc` binary.

  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc
  ', /Users/bruno/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.11.1/src/lib.rs:1227:10
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Here is my rust toolchain:

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/bruno/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-02-10-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-02-19-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-02-20-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-03-14-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-04-01-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
```

Comment: Answered here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/substrate-build-failure-with-runtime-benchmarks-flag

Answer (score 3):

```sh
arch -x86_64 brew install protobuf
```

Seemed to have done the job.